# Distinct Query is Sails js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I want to retrieve distinct records from mongodb .I tried the below method,

```
        Model.find()
             .distinct('username')
             .where({ age: 21 })
             .exec(function(err, user) { });
```

But iam getting error as below.

```
     TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'distinct'.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions are not really what you want, and there is a better way to get at the "good  stuff" in the model used by sails.

You really want the [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method for this, and as a sample, your equivalent would be:

```js
   Model.native(function(err,collection){
       collection.aggregate([
           { "$match": { "age": 21 } },
           { "$group": { "_id": '$username' } }
       ],function(err,docs) {
          // something here

       });
   });
```

For more under the hood parts, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22189084/2313887) for some more links on the Aggregation framework.