# Testing MySQL Updates Per Second Limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit

Let's say I have 1 table and 100 rows in this table. The table is simple and only contains an Auto Increment `ID` field and a `load_count` field.

Every time a web page is loaded this query is executed and `load_count` is increased by 1 ...

```
UPDATE table_name SET load_count = load_count + 1 WHERE ID = $id
```

How can I test the limit my server can handle this query per second. Will I run into errors at 10 page loads per second or at 1000?

How can I emulate 'x' number of page loads per second and record results for how MySQL performs?

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702643/mysql-vs-mongodb-1000-reads

Comment: @SpencerX that is not the op wants ?

Comment: Would this help? http://sqlloadgenerator.codeplex.com/

Comment: If not then maybe this? http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-stress-test-mysql-with-mysqlslap/