# Factors that MongoDB insert faster than MySQL insert? please explain to me?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, performance, database

can you explain to me, why MongoDB insert faster than MySQL insert? 
i use PHP 5.6 and MongoDB 3.2.12 and MySQL 5.6.25.

please give reference! book or journal

Answer (score 0):

(I reopened because the "dup" [MySQL vs MongoDB 1000 reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702643/mysql-vs-mongodb-1000-reads) was about reads, not inserts.)

MySQL can be very slow or very fast on `INSERTing`.  To be fair to MySQL, you should specify the specifics that lead to slow or fast.

- MyISAM versus InnoDB -- MyISAM is dying, don't consider it in any comparison.  https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/11/mysql-8-0-end-myisam/
- Batch the rows being inserted.  Inserting 100 rows in a single `INSERT` statement easily runs 10 times as fast as one row at a time.
- `LOAD DATA INFILE` (from a .csv) is even faster.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html
- Consider transactional flags in InnoDB to get some more speed.
- Secondary indexes have some impact.
- Inserting at the "end" of a table is faster than inserting at random locations -- think UUIDs or GUIDs.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid
- If the table is too big to be cached, UUID inserts eventually slow down to 1 row per IOP.
- Keep in mind that the only reason for inserting a table is to later fetch it.  So, the fetching patterns have some impact on the insertion optimizations.
- Etc, etc.