# MySQL vs MongoDB index performance

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB and MySQL to store the same table in respective formats and I have huge volumes of the data. I have created indexes on both the databases to fetch the data efficiently. I know that generally MongoDB is faster than MySQL. Since, I'm creating indexes on both the databases, so is the fetching speed is same in case of both the databases or is it like still MongoDB is faster? Please explain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL vs MongoDB 1000 reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702643/mysql-vs-mongodb-1000-reads)

Comment: Count the disk hits.  Generally an indexed lookup is faster than a table scan because of fewer disk hits.  I can help explain the disk hits for a given example in MySQL; if you can provide the same analysis for MongoDB, we can explain why one is faster than the other.  Or, as I expect, each product will be about the same speed because each needs about the same number of disk hits when optimally indexed.